# PHP not sending the UPDATE info to the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm not that big of a genius in PHP nor in SQL but I'm getting this strange error, where I see the info that I want to send to the data base on the link and I get no errors, however my database is not getting updated.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="PT">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>Alteração do produto</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $lig=new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "pie");
            if($lig->connect_errno != 0){
                echo ("Base de dados indisponível");
            }
            $instrucao=$lig->prepare("UPDATE produto SET produto1 = ? , quantidade1 = ? , preco1 = ? WHERE codigo1 = ?");
            $instrucao->bind_param("isid", $_GET['codigo1'], $_GET['produto1'], $_GET['quantidade1'], $_GET['preco1']);
            $resultado=$instrucao->execute();
            if($resultado==FALSE){
                    echo "<p>produto não editado</p>";
            }
            else {
                    //header( "Location: shoppinglist.php" );
            }
            $lig->close();
        ?>
        <form method="get">
            <label>Código: <input name="codigo1" readonly value="<?php echo $_GET['codigo1'] ?>"></label>
            <label>Nome: <input name="produto1" value="<?php echo $_GET['produto1'] ?>"></label>
            <label>Quantidade: <input name="quantidade1" value="<?php echo $_GET['quantidade1'] ?>"></label>
            <label>Preço: <input name="preco1" value="<?php echo $_GET['preco1'] ?>"></label>
            <button type="submit" value="POST">Alterar</button>
        </form>


    </body>
    </html>
```

I know that there can be some syntax errors on this code, and I'm sorry if so. Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you type that prepared statement into phpmyadmin with some values does it get updated? also you're not sanitizing your inputs at all which is a security flaw, but I'm guessing you'd rather have it first before worrying about security. Also your form values depend on GET requests, so are you sure those are getting filled in?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however Manuel already helped me solve this bellow. And this was a simple school project of a friend of mine I was helping, i was just binding the parameters in the wrong order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with

```
 $instrucao->bind_param("sidi", $_GET['produto1'], $_GET['quantidade1'], $_GET['preco1'], $_GET['codigo1']);
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you are binding the wrong params shouldn't the first one be $_GET['produto1'] (since it's the first one in the update statement..